# Associative array in an another array c#

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

How i can achieve this in C#:

```
myarr[x]["date1"]="text";
myarr[x]["date2]"="text"
```

Where x is a dynamic nr.  Basically I want to add to `myarr` array an associative array

Comment: What are you really trying to do?

Comment: I don't think C# array indexers can be `string`.

Comment: `myarr[0]["date1"]="text"; myarr[1]["date2]"="text"` and so on

Comment: @Tim Of course they can.  They can be of any type.

Comment: @Servy - Show me where `someArray["indexer"]` is valid.  My comment was about the indexer, not the type of the array.

Comment: Define `myarr` as `Dictionary<string,string>[]`

Comment: @Tim Done. `var someArray = new Dictionary<string,string>(); var something = someArray["indexer"];`  When I said the type of the key of the index can be of any value I meant it, I *wasn't* referring to the type of the value returned.

Comment: @Servy - Sure, that's valid - but I was talking about a simple array that contains another simple array. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C# an associative array would be a `Dictionary`.  Since you have two dimensions, that's a dictionary or dictionaries:

```
var myarr = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, string>>();
int x = 5;

myarr[x] = new Dictionary<string, string>();
myarr[x]["date1"] = "text";
myarr[x]["date2"] = "text";
```

Of course an associative array where the key is an integer, the keys start at 0, and are contiguous, would be represented as a C# array or `List`, so if your integer keys meet those constraints, then you may want to have a `List<Dictionary<string, string>>`.

Comment: And how do i add an element to 'myarr'? I'm searching the php behavior `$arr=array(); for() { $arr[$i++]=array('date'=>'text')`

Comment: @AndreyPon You can either use the `Add` method explicitly, or you can use the indexer, as I showed in my answer.  What I have is working code that you can compile and run.  If you have a method to create a `Dictionary<string,string>` you can simply assign it to `myarr` using the indexer and it will add that value using the indexer's property as the key.  If that key already exists it will overwrite that key's value.

Comment: I still don't get it, `var myarr = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, string>>();  for(int i=0;i<10;i++) myarr.Add(what?) or myarr[i]["date1"]="text" which gives an compiler error`

Comment: @AndreyPon I showed you *exactly* what you need to write in my answer.  You can take that exact code, replace `x` with a loop variable, and it'll work just fine.  If you're getting a compiler error, then you've changed the code in some way that you haven't shown.